# how to show posts that are missing a meta_value

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

How can I build a query to find posts that DO NOT contain a certain meta key or meta value?

for example:

```
query_posts( array( 
    'meta_query' => array(
        array( 'key' => 'feature', 'value' => '_wp_zero_value', 'compare' => '!=' )         )
) );
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Getting posts without a certain meta *key* is a little tricky, namely due to the database design and the nature of SQL joins.

AFAIK, the most efficient way would be to actually grab the post IDs that *do* have the meta key, and then exclude them from your query.

```
// get all post IDs that *have* 'meta_key' with a non-empty value
$posts = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'my_key' AND meta_value != ''" );

// get all posts *excluding* the ones we just found
query_posts( array( 'post__not_in' => $posts ) );
```

Answer (score 7):

```
$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR', //default AND
        array(
            'key' => 'feature',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'feature',
            'value' => '_wp_zero_value',
            'compare' => '='
        )
    ));

$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
var_dump($the_query);
```

Read further : [Wordpress Doc](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query#Usage)

NB: before the wordpress 3.9 there is a [bug](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/23268) So this is the work around

```
array(
       'key' => 'feature',
       'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
       'value' => '' //add this empty value check for check NOT EXISTS
      ),
```