# If meta key exists in get posts function otherwise create it

Tags: custom-field, post-meta, get-posts

The following code fetches posts with the meta key home telephone numbers.

```
$metas = ''; 
    $args = array(
    'numberposts' => 1,
    'post_type' => 'electors',
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'wpcf-home_telephone_number',
            'value' => '0',
            'compare' => '>'
        )
     ) 
    );


$canvassing = get_posts( $args );
```

I want to add another meta to look for. The problem is that this meta may not exist on all posts. I want to get posts that either don't have the meta key or don't have a value for it.

```
array(
            'key' => 'wpcf-success',

            'value' => ''
        )
```

This code will only get posts that have the key without a value. I also want posts that do not have this key at all.

I tired this `add_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-success', '', true);` but since we have not fetched the posts there is no post ID yet.

Comment: [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/21369/4771) may help you.

Answer (score 2):

This "not exists" functionality isn't possible using a regular meta query. It's being worked on, but it looks like it's been shuffled to a future release ([see this trac ticket](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18158) for more insight).

In the meantime, you have to run a custom SQL statement [using $wpdb](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_Generic_Results), as in [DeadMedic's answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21366/how-to-show-posts-that-are-missing-a-meta-value/21369#21369) that Milo linked to in the comments.